# perl fork() how to check if child crashed

Tags: perl, fork

I have some Perl code that generates a number of child processes. The basic code is as follows:

```
 my $forked = 0;
 my $err = 0;
 my $Processes_To_Use_After_Calc=10;     
 print "Parent ($$) has started\n";
 for my $ispawn (1 .. $Processes_To_Use_After_Calc){
    my $child_pid = fork();
    die "Cannot fork: $!" if !defined $child_pid; # system overload
    if(defined $child_pid && $child_pid > 0) {
        ## Parent
        $forked++;
    } elsif(defined $child_pid){
        #
        # Here some calculations are performed
        #
        print "Child $$ has finished (number $ispawn) \n";
    }
}
for(1..$forked) {
    my $child_pid = wait();
}
```

All fairly standard stuff. Now, I would like to know if any of the child processes crash (failed to terminate correctly). Clearly if the last statement of each child process is not printed I could assume there was a problem. However I would like another method that would exit the parent program completely and close all child processes that were still open if one of the child processes crashes. Is this possible?

Comment: What are the exit codes of crashing children? `wait()` returns that exit code, so you can act on that.

Comment: `wait` returns a process id but sets the exit code in `$?` as a side-effect.

Comment: "_failrly standard stuff_" -- note though that the blocking `wait` waits for one process one at a time. So if something takes longer you won't know about any others before that one's done. (And what if one locks up?) Consider a loop with non-blocking (`WNOHANG`) `waitpid` instead. There are examples in [waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html) and [perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)

Comment: Also, there is no need for `defined` test in the `if-elsif` branches since you nicely check right after the `fork` whether it returned `undef`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`wait` sets `$?`

> Behaves like `wait(2)` on your system: it waits for a child process to terminate and returns the pid of the deceased process, or `-1` if there are no child processes. The status is returned in `$?` and $`{^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}`.

So,

```
my $child_pid = wait();

if    ( $? == -1  ) { die "wait failed: $!\n"; }
elsif ( $? & 0x7F ) { warn "Child $child_pid killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n"); }
elsif ( $? >> 8   ) { warn "Child $child_pid exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"); }
else                { print "Child $child_pid exited successfully\n"; }
```

If the program truly crashed, you'd get `Child killed by signal 11`, which is `SIGSEGV`.

If it threw an uncaught exception, you'd likely get `Child exited with error XXX`. The exact value will vary by program and could be meaningless. By default, Perl uses `$! || ($? >> 8) || 255` for exit value on an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 3):

As per the document for `wait`:

> Behaves like wait(2) on your system: it waits for a child process to
>                  terminate and returns the pid of the deceased process, or "-1" if
>                  there are no child processes.  The status is returned in $?  and
>                  "${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}".  Note that a return value of "-1" could
>                  mean that child processes are being automatically reaped, as
>                  described in perlipc.

If your child was killed by a signal, `$? & 0x7F` will be true and equal to the number of the signal that killed the child.

Comment: The POSIX module has [functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#WAIT) for examining the return value to find out why it exited. OP probably needs `WIFSIGNALED()`.

Comment: It's the other way. A normal non-zero exit code will be shifted 8 bits to the right (multiplied by 256) in `$?`. When `$?` is greater than 0 but less than 256, it holds the signal number that terminated the child process.

Comment: @mob, Not quite either. Only the lower 7 bits hold the signal number. The 8th indicates a core dump. Fixed the answer.